# Can an Israeli citizen enter Israel with an expired Israeli passport?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, israel

Basically the question:

Israeli citizen's passport has expired while abroad.  Is it possible to reenter Israel with an expired passport?

Comment: Out of interest, do you carry another valid passport so that the airline would allow you to board, or should that be added to your question, whether you can board (on a non-stop flight) to Israel with an expired Israeli passport?

Comment: @Dorothy I am not an Israeli citizen but yes a person has another valid passport.  It may be worthwhile as a separate question though.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, [Israel Ministry of Foreign Affiars Consular Services FAQ](http://mfa.gov.il/MFA/ConsularServices/Pages/Consular-Services-FAQ.aspx#blank) has the following in the Travel Documents section, although the question is *Can I enter and exit Israel with my foreign passport?* [emphasis mine]

An Israeli citizen must enter and exit Israel with his Israeli passport. If you cannot wait here for issuance of a new passport, **you can enter Israel with your Israeli passport even though its validity date has expired**. However during your stay in Israel you must go to the Population, Immigration and Border Authority in order to renew your passport for the purpose of exiting Israel.